# CQ DataSourcePool java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pool not open

Tags: osgi, aem, apache-commons-dbcp

I have configured Adobe CQ to use connection pooling to handle connections with MySql database. Everything works fine, but after a few hours I see this exception while trying to connect to database.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pool not open
        at org.apache.commons.pool.BaseObjectPool.assertOpen(BaseObjectPool.java:99)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:917)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:96)
```

I have seen such errors being reported in several instances/applications. I wanted to know if there is something wrong with the way this works on CQ.

I am using CQ5.6.1 and below is the code snippet I use to get a connection

```
@Reference
private DataSourcePool dataSourceService;
DataSource ds;
Connection connection;
        try{
            ds = (DataSource)   dataSourceService.getDataSource("datasource_name);
            connection = ds.getConnection();//this line causes the exception
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{ connection.close(); }
```

This is my datasource configuration
[image]

Is there anything that I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. You need to double check your configurations. Check in OSGI, check on your code every little detail for your database settings. These are the two things to look at. Then try to install the bundle/package again.